# script to grep "a line" from multiples files named 1,2,3,....60

Tags: bash, grep

I want to grep `lines :` from multiple files with a bash script. I have directories named as 1,2,3,4,5,.... 60. For one directory I would use command like

```
grep "line : " ./1/file.dat |tail -1
```

But I want to use it for 60 directories.

Can you pleasr help me with the command.

Comment: The title and the question don't really match, me thinks?

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we're not all guessing at what you need. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `grep | tail -1`, use `grep -m 1` to stop after the first match. This is easier to extend to multiple files.

```
grep -m 1 'line : ' ./*/file.dat
```

or

```
grep -m 1 'line : ' ./{1..60}/file.dat
```

Comment: `tail -1` would print the last match, what you're suggesting would print the first match so probably isn't what the OP wants. Without sample input and expected output we're guessing though.

Answer (score 0):

If want the last occurrence of `line :` in each of those files:

```
for file in ./{1..60}/file.dat; do grep "line :" $file | tail -1; done
```

If you want *all* matches of `line :` in those files, skip the `tail`:

```
grep "line :" ./{1..60}/file.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk instead of `grep`:

```
$ awk '/lines :/{print;nextfile}' {1,60}/file.dat
...lines :...
...etc...
```

Explained:

```
/lines :/ {       # if record in file matches "lines :"
    print         # output the record
    nextfile      # skip to next file
}                 # all good things must come to an end
```

Comment: `tail -1` would print the last match, what you're suggesting would print the first match so probably isn't what the OP wants. Without sample input and expected output we're guessing though.

Answer (score 0):

To output the ***last*** matched line from each `file.dat` file in each directory:

```
for f in ./t*/file.dat; do tac "$f" | grep -m1 'line : '; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `grep` with `awk`.

```
grep "line :" ./{1..60}/file.dat | awk -F ":" '
   NR==1 {lastfile=$1; lastline=$0; next}
   lastfile!=$1 {print lastline}
   {lastfile=$1; lastline=$0}
   END {print lastline}
   '
```

This is an anti-pattern, awk is smart enough for doing the matching. You get the same result with:

```
awk '
   fname!=FILENAME { if (last) print fname ":" last; last=""; }
   {fname=FILENAME}
   /line :/ {last=$0}
   ' ./{1..60}/file.dat
```